# Add An Input (Min) To An Array With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, function

Currently I have:

```
function generateRange(min, max, step){

    let rangeList = [];

    return rangeList.push(min);

}

console.log(generateRange((2, 10, 2)));
```

And in this case it's returning `1`. That doesn't make any sense to me - shouldn't it be returning `2`? Do I need to get the value of `min` as I push it into the new array?

Ultimately, I'll want to have the array look like this:

`[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

With 2 as the min, 10 as the max, and 2 as the increment.

Comment: `push` returns the array's length

Comment: Note that `push()` returns the new length of the array (counting the new inserted element).

Comment: Oh okay - what method should I use to add the element to the new array, then? Concat()?

Comment: use `concat` or return the array in a separate line.

Comment: You can use `push()`, but you have to do `rangeList.push(min); return rangeList;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.concat()`, unless you want to return on a new, separate line from the one where you used `.push()`.

I.e. this will work:

```
function generateRange (min, max, step) {

    let rangeList = [];

    return rangeList.concat(min);

}
```

And this will work:

```
function generateRange (min, max, step) {

    let rangeList = [];

    rangeList.push(min);

    return rangeList;
}
```

And if you want `min`, `max`, and everything in-between based on the `step` value, use a for-loop with the given values as the min, max, and increment:

```
function generateRange(min, max, step){
    let rangeList = [];
    for(let i = min; i <= max; i += step) {
        rangeList.push(i);
    }
    return rangeList;
}
console.log(generateRange(2, 10, 2));
```

Therefore you can use `.push()` to create a new array, just don't use return in the same line of code because it will return the length of the array instead of the actual array.

Answer (score 1):

The push method returns the length of the new array, and it's 1 after push a single element.

You can use `Array.from()` to generate the range:

```js
const generateRange = (min, max, step = 1) =>
  Array.from({ length: Math.floor((max - min) / step) + 1 }, (_, i) =>
    min + i * step
  )

console.log(generateRange(2, 10, 2));
```

Comment: Is there any way you can simplify this? Why do you have `step = 1` as a parameter? Could you write this as a declarative function?

Comment: `step = 1` is a default value for `step` if not stated. This is the most declarative I can go with array from. The main idea is - find the length of result array, and create a new array via Array.from. Each item in the array is the `min + i * step` - `i` is the current index, and it starts at 0.

Comment: But step is passed-in as `2`? Do you have to say `step = 1` anyway?

Comment: If you pass 2 the step will be 2, the same goes for any other value. If you don't pass a step, it will be one. See [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). You can omit it, it's just for convenience.